# calculate business days using IBM ODM

Tags: websphere, business-rules, odm, ibm-odm

I have a requirement where the start date, time period and geography location will be passed on from the frontend to IBM ODM.

IBM ODM then based on the geographical location, calculates the next date based on the time period and the holidays/working days in that geography.

I am thinking to have a decision table which will have the geography and corresponding holidays for a year and a month. In the rule, we will have a calculation of the next date based on the geography and holidays.

Please let me know if this is the correct way of implementation.

Thanks

Comment: The problem you are solving is not clear. What is it your are looking for? Is it the first business day on or after the Start Date? If so, what does Time Period contribute? Or is the problem to determine how many business days are within the the time period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your next date exactly? Do you need to calculate next consultation date based on start date, time period and geographical holiday list?

If my above assumption is correct, you need a dynamic domain which loads holidays.

When you add start date with a time period completion date, you need to check whether that day is holiday or not. If so, the next day should be a consultation day. Otherwise, that day should be a consultation date.

If you want the same rule to be applicable for many other conditions, go with a decision table. If not, a simple rule is enough.

Thanks
Mohammed Khaleel